# Plugin Filetrip dá erro - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um formulário no wordpress feito com plugin Caldera Forms. Usei o plugin Filetrip para fazer o upload dos arquivos do formulário e enviar o link por e-mail desses arquivos, tudo estava funcionando corretamente até que do NADA hoje, eu não consigo fazer upload de arquivos.

Configurei o plugin para aceitar apenas PDF com tamanhos até 10M, mas eu tento anexo um PDF com 2M ele não vai. Pára na metade do caminho e a mensagem que eu vejo é:

"Failed to open output stream"

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que o Filetrip procura uma pasta na raiz do plugin, chamada UPLOADS. Como não encontra ele dá esse erro.

Eu apenas criei essa pasta, UPLOADS, dentro da pasta FILETRIP-PLUGIN segue o caminho:

wp-content/plugins/filetrip-plugin/

E dei a permissão para essa pasta de 775.

Pronto, problema resolvido!!